# Query against two separate Redshift clusters in a single query?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am designing my db structure, and wondering if possible to run a single query against two separate Redshift clusters?

If possible, any limitation on the region, availability zones, VPC groups, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's no possible in Redshift directly. <s>Additionally you cannot query across multiple databases on the *same* cluster.</s>

---

UPDATE: Redshift announced a preview for cross database queries on 2020-10-15 - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cross-database-overview.html

---

You could use an external tool such as Amazon Athena or Presto running on an EMR cluster to do this. You would define each Redshift cluster as an external data source. Be careful though, you will lose most of Redshift's performance optimizations and a lot of data will have to be pulled back into Athena / Presto to answer your queries.

As an alternative to cross-cluster queries, consider placing your data onto S3 in well partitioned Parquet or ORC files and using Redshift Spectrum (or Amazon Athena) to query them. This approach allows multiple clusters to query a common data set while maintaining good query performance. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/

Comment: Cross database queries are now in preview but only for Redshift clusters running RA3 instances. So it will be possible to fetch data from a different database running on the same Redshift cluster

Comment: Cross-cluster queries are now supported as well on RA3 nodes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/datashare-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Using federated queries in Amazon Redshift, a second cluster tables can be accessed as an external schema

You can refer to documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/federated_query_example.html